# why the variable is working inside the function but not when it is placed outside the function though it has global scope?

Tags: javascript, variables, dom, scope

i am using this code to change the images on clicking it again and again :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    
    <script src="C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\light bulb\js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <img id="goku" src="C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/normal goku.png" onclick="goku()">
    </div>
</body>





<!--javascript code-->
let click = 1;
let x = document.getElementById('goku');
function goku() {
    
    switch(click)
    {
        case 1 :
            x.src = "C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/normal goku.png";click++;break;
        case 2 :
            x.src = "C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/super saiyan goku.png";click++;break;
        case 3 : 
        x.src = "C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/super saiyan 3.jpg";click++;break;
        case 4 : 
        x.src = "C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/super saiyan blue.jpg";click=1;break;
    }
}
```

but it is not working.

And , when i put the  `let x = document.getElementById('goku');`  inside the function , it is working fine. If this is because of the scope of the variable , then it should also applied on `click` variable but `click` variable is working fine.
Do you have any explanation for this behaviour ?

Comment: Your script tag needs to be just _before_ the ending body tag. Currently, your script executes _before_ body of the html document is parsed. Because of this, `document.getElementById('goku')` will return `null`.

Comment: Depending on the browser, the script is not even loaded. HTML files with file protocol are problematic. Make your life easier, and install a local server.

Comment: You need wait until document ready, because when yo fill the x var the document are not ready. that's why the script tag must be located at the end of body tag

Answer (score 0):

this because your script runs before body content load
you can fix it with changing html content like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img id="goku" src="C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/normal goku.png" onclick="goku()">
    </div>
    <script src="C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\light bulb\js.js"></script>
</body>
```

or you can define x inside the function like this

```js
let click = 1;
function goku(e) {
    let x = e.target
    switch(click)
    {
        case 1 :
            x.src = "C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/normal goku.png";
            click++;
            break;
        case 2 :
            x.src = "C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/super saiyan goku.png";
            click++;
            break;
        case 3 : 
            x.src = "C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/super saiyan 3.jpg";
            click++;
            break;
        case 4 : 
            x.src = "C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/super saiyan blue.jpg";
            click=1;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is executed before the `img` element is added to the document.

If `let x = document.getElementById('goku')` is outside the function, the element does not exist yet when that line is executed.
If it is inside the function, the line is executed when the button is clicked, thus long after the element has been added into the document.

You may move the `script` tag at the end of `<body>` (just after `</div>`), or wait until the `document` is ready to call `getElementById`.